# how to show multiple line notification in android?

Tags: android

I doing one notification with multiple line, code like:

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, Home.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("");
    //
    // Set Big View style to see full content of the message
    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle inboxStyle =
            new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();

    inboxStyle.setBuilder(mBuilder);
    inboxStyle.bigText(msg);
    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("");
    inboxStyle.setSummaryText("");
    // Moves the big view style object into the notification object.
    mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
    mBuilder.setContentText(msg);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build()); 
}
```

But it's only show one line notification, I would like it show all content of notification with multiple line. Can you help me?

Thanks you so much

Answer (score 4):

There are three styles to be used with the big view: big picture style, big text style, Inbox style. The following code demonstrates the usage of the BigTextStyle() which allows to use up to 256 dp.

```
String longText = "...";

Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this).
.....
.setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(longText))
```

for more reference ,check this [reference link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html)

Comment: Android 4.1 supports expandable notifications

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done. Just use the Big View for notification. See the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Here is a good [tutorial by vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Big view in Notifications:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#BigNotify

Answer (score 0):

try to add both `SetStyle` and `SetPriorityas` as the following :

```
  .SetStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().BigText(message.Long_Message))   
  .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.Max)
```

it is working fine for me :)